# Parking domains and avoiding so called "search engine penalities"

Tags: web-hosting, domain-registration

I have purchased two **domains from one particular registrar** and **hosting from GoDaddy**.

Assume they are **domain1.com** and **domain2.com**

Assume my hosting IP address is **111.111.111.111**

I added both domain1.com and domain2.com in my domain management control panel in GoDaddy. I got GoDaddy's nameservers and set them for both the domains at my registrar's control panel. So, now, both domains point to same hosting IP.

When I ping "domain1.com" or "domain2.com" the results say -

```
Pinging domain1.com [111.111.111.111] with 32 bytes of data:

Pinging domain2.com [111.111.111.111] with 32 bytes of data:
```

respectively. So, they both point to the same hosting IP.

**BUT, internally, I have configured IIS to point them to different folders so that different websites are shown.** (My hosting plan is expensive and I intend to use the space and bandwidth for many websites). But still, technically, all domains point to same IP address.

Is this a bad thing? Is this what is called "domain parking"?

I read some search engine forum posts that two domains pointing to the same IP/Website will be penalised by search engines and stuff.

I have also read that simply "parking" the domains won't attract penality. I don't know whether what I have done is parking or the so called "wrong" thing.

Can someone shed light on what I have done and what I should do? I don't want to be blacklisted by any search engine.

P.S. I know this is not a search engine forum, but I am new to website hosting and domains and I am very weak in nearly all technical terms and concepts relating to web hosting and domains. I thought this will be a good place to understand these things.

**Properly Updated: Different Domains, Same Hosting IP, Different IIS Virtual Directory - so different website shown.**

Comment: I thought parking was when you bought it, but never changed a thing. Like, when you browse to a parked domain, it takes you to the "Coming Soon!" thing that the particular registrar has as a default. You are actually pointing them to a legit site.

Comment: If my understand of "parking domains" looks like it is wrong, it probably is :D So, if a domain points to some IP address and some website is shown when people visit it, then it is not called parking. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't "penalized", the problem is that you now share the pagerank and traffic between those two. (It's like splitting the ticket in an election)

- domain1.com has 500,000 inbound links
- domain2.com has 500,000 inbound links

So in effect, your site has 1 million inbound links. However, Google thinks you have 2 different sites each with 500,000 links, so it hurts your overall ranking.

**Edit due to question update**

You have two different domains pointing to do different sets of content... then those are two independent sites and no search engine (at least not one that you would care about) would penalize you for those sites having the same IP.

Comment: Hi, please forgive me, the previous version of my question was wrong. Can you look at it again? I was actually going to serve two completely different content websites for those two domains. I got confused and added wrong info in the question.

Comment: @senthilkumar-c - Ok, I updated the answer

Comment: +1 Hi, I got confused between "same IP" and "same website". Thanks for explaining the difference :)

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't sound like 'domain parking' to me, this sounds like you have the IIS equivalent of apache httpd's name-based VirtualHosts

if you are penalized by a search engine, it's not a very good search engine, since each domain is most likely serving different data. and if their filters aren't smart enough to understand that, then they probably haven't been doing the search engine business for long.

lots of people host multiple sites from the same IP. domain 'parking' services host extremely similar content off the same ip, probably hundreds of sites off one IP. a dozen or less, serving different date, should not be a problem.